# Why do chainlink price feeds and other services not work on local chains or javascript VMs?

Tags: remix, price

I deployed the remix on vm, the result was returning zero. I hooked up my own metamask and it returns a value close to the correct result. Why didn't it work in Javascript VM?

Answer (score 1):

[Chainlink](https://chain.link/) is what's known as a layer 2. This means it's built **on top of an existing chain.**

On mainnets and testnets, there are Chainlink nodes monitoring those blockchains to respond to requests. There aren't any Chainlink nodes monitoring your local chain, or virtual machine, since those exist only on your machine!

Additionally, if you want to work with Chainlink price feeds, those only exist on specific chains as well. For example, you couldn't work with [Aave](https://aave.com/) on a local chain, since it was never deployed to your local chain.

---

All this being said, it's still important to test locally using Chainlink technology, and deployed contracts. This is where [forking](https://hardhat.org/guides/mainnet-forking.html) and [mocking](https://blog.chain.link/testing-chainlink-smart-contracts/) come into play. If you're testing a smart contract locally that uses chainlink, you'll want to mock the calls.

Here is a link to learning more about [testing Chainlink smart contracts](https://blog.chain.link/testing-chainlink-smart-contracts/) and some [example tests](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit/tree/main/test) [more tests](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix/tree/master/tests).

Comment: Thanks Patrick, as a beginner I needed a way to test getting prices from data (price) feeds and forking mainnet helped, following the hardhat docs.

Answer (score 0):

Chainlink price feeds are deployed contracts that you could interact with. Any contracts you create that are dependent on specific Chainlink price feeds aren't going to work if you deploy them on a network that doesn't have those feeds (e.g., deploying a contract that is dependent on a specific Kovan-deployed Chainlink price feed to another network like Ropsten or a local blockchain like Ganache). By the way, JavaScript VM is just another local blockchain that runs in your browser, so make sure any contracts you deploy there don't have any assumptions of pre-existing contracts like price feeds.